# Error with axShockwaveFlash in C#

Tags: c#, activex

I'm using *axShockwaveFlash* in my C# project.
I don't know why it gives me error:

> *Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))*

platform of target is x86.
what should I do now to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'v solved it myself.
I installed adobe flash CS5 then it fi

Comment: can u add the download link for adobe flash cs5 which you used.

Comment: i insalled adobe flash pro cs5, but still i am facing the same issue. do i need to include a different reference from flash cs5 software?

Comment: my issue solved after installing latest adobe flash player activex v21    https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/21/flashplayer_21_ax_debug.exe.. your ans was 3 years old which includes activx v10 which wont work today.