# Class not registered Error appears when AxShockwaveFlash used under windows 7 development environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, flash

My project is to enable the application usable under windows 7 as it is already working under Windows XP. This application has to play .swf file under windows 7. When i try to play a .swf file using the class AxShockwaveFlash, i am getting an error as

```
{"Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))"}.
```

while executing this line

```
AxShockwaveFlash flash = new AxShockwaveFlash();
flash.BeginInit();
flash.Location = new Point(50, 80);
flash.Name = "FlashMovie";
flash.TabIndex = 1;
this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
this.panel1.Controls.Add(flash);
flash.Size = new Size(100, 100);
flash.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
flash.EndInit();  //Exception occurs here
```

Though this error is discussed already in stackoverflow, my issue is different. 
i already tried : [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496214/how-to-solve-com-exception-class-not-registered-exception-from-hresult-0x80040) , [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077477/class-not-registered-exception-from-hresult-0x80040154-regdb-e-classnotreg), [Solution 3](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/241493/Class-not-registered-Exception-from-HRESULT-x#answer1),  [Solution 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415352/flash-ocx-class-not-registered-on-windows-7-x64/3677516?noredirect=1#comment60191545_3677516)  but none of them solved my issue. 
This [solution 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815166/error-with-axshockwaveflash-in-c-sharp) is not a proper one because CS5 is a big software i cannot use it as a prerequisite for my application.

I have already installed Adobe Shockwave player from [link](https://get.adobe.com/shockwave/)'.
I have tried project configuration under : Any CPU, x86 also..

For simplicity i tried a basic desktop application from [source](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/how-to-play-flash-in-windows-forms-application-using-C-Sharp/download/FlashInWinForms.zip)(use Form1 not Form2) which works fine when i debug and run it under dev machine with Windows XP but same application throws class not registered error when run under windows 7 dev machine.

```
axShockwaveFlash1 = new AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash();
axShockwaveFlash1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
panel1.Controls.Add(axShockwaveFlash1);    //Exception occurs here
axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = @"~/myflash.swf";
axShockwaveFlash1.Play();
```

Kindly provide me a solution to run .swf file under asp.net windows form application with windows 7 environment.

Comment: Have you checked the registry on the Windows 7 machine to see if the ShockWave classes really are registered?

Comment: @cdkMoose how to check the same?

Comment: Solution 5 is also not working in my case. same issue still persist.

Comment: Run the registry editor and search for it by name or clsid.  You should find it under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is the case, you can check with your internal configurations. Try installing the ActiveX plugin of Adobe. It worked for me.

Comment: thanks for your help, i installed adobe flash player activex v21 . it worked.. thanks and voted +1 for your ans